# Projection Formula for Projective Morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question about a step in the proof of 5.3.17 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 201):

[image]

My question is why does Prop. 3.1.24 imply that

$$\mathcal{O}_{SpecB} \cong q_*\mathcal{O}_{X_B}$$

hold? Is it a consequence of the projection formula? Which role play the assumption that $q$ is projective? Does it fulfill a special case of projection formula?

Comment: The assumption in Theorem 3.15 (and also in 3.17) is that  $f$ is projective and $\mathcal{O}_Y = f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$. Since projective morphisms are stable under base change it follows that $q$ is projective.  The condition on structure sheaves $f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$ is stable under flat base change (by Prop. 3.1.24), and this is why $q_\ast \mathcal{O}_{X_B} = \mathcal{O}_{Spec B}$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: hmmm I'm stil not sure  how the Prop. 3.1.24 imply that $f_\ast \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$ is stable under flat base change. Naively we have only the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \otimes B \to \mathcal{O}_{X_B}(X_B)$. Futhermore since localisations are flat and therefore $A \to B \to B_f$ flat for a $f \in B$ we get again by 1.24 an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \otimes B_f \to \mathcal{O}_{X_{B_f}}(X_{B_f})$. Looks good at first glimpse since no problem for restricting to open subsets. But here I see following problem:

Comment: We want to show $q_\ast \mathcal{O}_{X_B} = \mathcal{O}_{Spec B}$. So let take an open $U \subset Spec(B)$. Since $D(f)$ with $f \in B$ form a base wlog $U= D(f)$.

We insert: $q_*\mathcal{O}_{X_B}(D(f))= \mathcal{O}_{X_B}(q^{-1}(D(f)))$. But does $\mathcal{O}_{X_B}(q^{-1}(D(f)))= \mathcal{O}_X(X) \otimes_A B_f$ hold and why? We have only the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \otimes B_f \cong \mathcal{O}_{X_{B_f}}(X_{B_f})$ but does also $\mathcal{O}_{X_{B_f}}(X_{B_f})= \mathcal{O}_{X_B}(q^{-1}(D(f)))$ hold?

Comment: Do you see an argument? This poses the only problem to me since as soon as we find out why this holds we know by assumption that $\mathcal{O}_X(X) =A$ so we are done